# how can I convert python tuple to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I convert the following list of tuples:

```
t = [("x", "1","11"),("x", "2","22"),("x", "3","33"),
     ("y", "3","00"),("z", "2","222"), ("z", "3","333")]
```

to this list of lists with dictionaries?

```
[["x",{"1":"11","2":"22","3":"33"}],
 ["y",{"3":"00"}],
 ["z",{"2":"222","3":"333"}]]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I've presumed that using a list of *tuples* in your output is fine too; that makes it possible to use `dict.items()` returns without having to map those back to lists. It's trivial to convert between tuples and lists, in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two steps: create a dictionary and track the order you've seen the first elements, then build a list from that:

```
order = []
mapping = {}
for outer, inner, value in t:
    if outer not in order:
        order.append(outer)
    mapping.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value

result = [(k, mapping[k]) for k in order]
```

or use a [`collections.OrderedDict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to track the order you first saw the outer keys in:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mapping = OrderedDict()
for outer, inner, value in t:
    mapping.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value

result = mapping.items()
```

If order isn't important, use the first version and remove all references to `order` (3 lines), and just use `mapping.items()` at the end.

If your input is always sorted on the first element of each tuple, you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = [(k, {k: v for _, k, v in g}) for k, g in groupby(t, itemgetter(0))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> t = [("x", "1","11"),("x", "2","22"),("x", "3","33"),
...      ("y", "3","00"),("z", "2","222"), ("z", "3","333")]
>>> order = []
>>> mapping = {}
>>> for outer, inner, value in t:
...     if outer not in order:
...         order.append(outer)
...     mapping.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value
... 
>>> [(k, mapping[k]) for k in order]
[('x', {'1': '11', '3': '33', '2': '22'}), ('y', {'3': '00'}), ('z', {'3': '333', '2': '222'})]
>>> mapping.items()  # ignoring order
[('y', {'3': '00'}), ('x', {'1': '11', '3': '33', '2': '22'}), ('z', {'3': '333', '2': '222'})]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mapping = OrderedDict()
>>> for outer, inner, value in t:
...     mapping.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value
... 
>>> mapping.items()
[('x', {'1': '11', '3': '33', '2': '22'}), ('y', {'3': '00'}), ('z', {'3': '333', '2': '222'})]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [(k, {k: v for _, k, v in g}) for k, g in groupby(t, itemgetter(0))]
[('x', {'1': '11', '3': '33', '2': '22'}), ('y', {'3': '00'}), ('z', {'3': '333', '2': '222'})]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of list comprehension. Here's a simple solution using it:

```
keys = set(map(lambda x: x[0], t))
d = [[k, dict([(y, z) for x, y, z in t if x is k])] for k in keys]
```

Result:

```
[['y', {'3': '00'}],
 ['x', {'1': '11', '2': '22', '3': '33'}],
 ['z', {'2': '222', '3': '333'}]]
```

This will be slow for larger lists as d is computed in O(N^2) time.